# errors when trying to retrieve a password value from a database

Tags: java, mysql

First off, I understand there is probably a better way to access stored passwords.  This is a basic project trying to prove a basic concept.

I am having problems trying to validate a users login with a database.

```
while(inputValue == null) {
            System.out.println(PASSWORD_MESSAGE);
            inputValue = in.nextLine();

            try {
                rs = statement.executeQuery(PASSWORD_QUERY);
                while(rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("TEST");
                    if(inputValue.equals(rs.getString("password"))) {
                        passwordValue = inputValue;
                        password= true;
                        break;
                    } 
                    if(!inputValue.equals(rs.getString("password"))){
                        System.out.println(ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        inputValue = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

the value *`PASSWORD_QUERY`* is (`SELECT password FROM project.account WHERE username='" + usernameValue + "'`)

I have double checked this query in the database and it does work fine.  my error happens at the while loop.  In debug mode it never enters the while loop and the `system.out` message *"TEST"* never goes to the console.

Comment: Can you try querying without the schema name i.e. SELECT password FROM account WHERE username='" + usernameValue + "' . Now there is limited basis why i am saying this. If it never gets into the loop , it only means that the result set is empty , trying to see why that is empty this can be a first step

Comment: Am I right you're loop never starts? inputValue == null. Shouldn't it be inputValue != null ?

Comment: that did not work ramachandran, same results.   To be clear m0rjjj, the moment the code gets to the line (while(rs.next()) it skips the loop.  there is a value inside the table set,  to be clear the table it is retrivieing information from is not null.

Answer (score 0):

The error was actually in the query to the db.  The variable the query was using was a static variable.  I did not realize that the variables value for a constant would never change.